# binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--)
    {
        int n, m;
        cin >> n >> m;
        vector <vector<int> > A(m, vector<int>(2));
        vector<int> possible;
        vector<int> set;
        int i;
        for (i = 0;i < m;i++)
        {
            cin >> A[i][0] >> A[i][1];
            possible.push_back(A[i][0]);
            possible.push_back(A[i][1]);
        }
            sort(possible.begin(), possible.end());
            int j = 0;
            bool size = 0;
            for (i = 0;i < possible.size();i++)
            {
                set.push_back(possible[i]);
                while (possible[i] == set[j])
                {
                    i++;
                    if (i == possible.size())
                    {
                        size = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (size)
                    break;
                i--;
                j++;
            }
            vector<int> iter;
            for (i = A.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
            {
                auto it1 = find(A.begin(), A.end(), A[i][0]);
                auto it2 = find(A.begin(), A.end(), A[i][1]);
                if ((it1 != A.end()) && (it2 != A.end()))
                {
                    iter.push_back(i);
                    A.erase(it1);
                    A.erase(it2);
                }
            }
            for (i = iter.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
                cout << iter[i] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

this is a code i wrote for a problem i found on codechef, anyway heres the thing, i keep getting the error `binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` going through the xutility "page", quite simply put, i dont even know why i get this error could someone please explain whats going on
heres the code snippet that i'm redirected to when i double click on the error

```
template<class _InIt,
    class _Ty> inline
    _InIt _Find_unchecked1(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, const _Ty& _Val, false_type)
    {   // find first matching _Val
    for (; _First != _Last; ++_First)
        if (*_First == _Val)
            break;
    return (_First);
    }
```

also, could anyone explain what the auto keyword does, i'm kinda iffy on its usage, could someone explain that as well

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

In

```
auto it1 = find(A.begin(), A.end(), A[i][0]);
auto it2 = find(A.begin(), A.end(), A[i][1]);
```

You are passing iterators to a 2d vector into `find` and trying to find a single `int`.  This will not work as the element type of `A` is a `std::vector<int>`, not an `int`.

Judging from your code it looks like you meant to do

```
auto it1 = find(A[i].begin(), A[i].end(), A[i][0]);
auto it2 = find(A[i].begin(), A[i].end(), A[i][1]);
```

Which gets the vector at the i'th index and finds a `int` in those vectors.

---

I would also like to mention that`using namespace std;` and `vector<int> set;` can cause some fun problems.  `set` is a member of `std` so the compiler can get confused when it sees `set` as you could be referring to a type or a variable.  The simplest way to fix that is to just get rid of `using namespace std;`.  For more on this see: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;


    int main()
    {
        int t;
        cin >> t;
        while (t--)
        {
            int n, m;
            cin >> n >> m;
            vector <vector<int> > A(m, vector<int>(2));
            vector<int> possible;
            vector<int> set;
            int i;
            for (i = 0;i < m;i++)
            {
                cin >> A[i][0] >> A[i][1];
                possible.push_back(A[i][0]);
                possible.push_back(A[i][1]);
            }
                sort(possible.begin(), possible.end());
                int j = 0;
                bool size = 0;
                for (i = 0;i < possible.size();i++)
                {
                    set.push_back(possible[i]);
                    while (possible[i] == set[j])
                    {
                        i++;
                        if (i == possible.size())
                        {
                            size = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (size)
                        break;
                    i--;
                    j++;
                }
                vector<int> iter;
                for (i = A.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
                {
                    auto it1 = find(A[i].begin(), A[i].end(), A[i][0]);
                    auto it2 = find(A[i].begin(), A[i].end(), A[i][1]);
                    if ((it1 != A[i].end()) && (it2 != A[i].end()))
                    {
                        iter.push_back(i);
                        A[i].erase(it1);
                        A[i].erase(it2);
                    }
                }
                for (i = iter.size() - 1;i >= 0;i--)
                    cout << iter[i] << " ";
                cout << endl;
            }
            return 0;
    }
```

you were missing the fact that A is a 2d vector so on line 51 and below that you should access the array using A[i].
You can read about auto here - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto

Hope this helps !